# Can i implement Row level security in power bi Rest Api approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have registered Client app from [power bi](https://dev.powerbi.com/apps)

Implemented RLS(row level security) in desktop for report, and publish to power bi portal.

using  [power bi Rest Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn877544.aspx) approach embedded the report into my web application.

the problem is the report showing all information which is not required for user.
Is it possible to have RLS(Row level security) for the report?

It is possible in [Azure power bi embedded api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/), has

```
var embedToken = PowerBIToken.CreateReportEmbedToken(this.workspaceCollection, this.workspaceId, report.Id, "Andrew Ma", ["Manager"]);'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, He gave answer for my query

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfkVljh_9O4&list=PLv2BtOtLblH2Rm9trJPuxmN8Kr8WFv7O0&index=2

[image]